# iPhone voicemail does not display my messages, tells me to call voicemail

Tags: iphone, ios

i have an iphone 6 running iOS 11.0.3. I recently received a sound from my phone indicating a voicemail, even though no phone call preceded it. When I check my voicemail, I see a blank screen with 'Call Voicemail' in the center. If I push on the message a phone pad comes up for me to call voicemail. I've never done this so I called my own number. It asked for my password. I don't recall ever setting up a password. I made some guesses but they didn't work. Why am I getting this call voicemail message and is there anything to do if I can't recall my password?

Comment: This is carrier specific and probably an issue they created by accident, afraid you’ll have to contact customer service.  Either their voicemail is broken, or that don’t have your number configured for visual voicemail.  (PS - it also might magically fix itself if it just happened out of nowhere-give it a few hours)

Comment: Also try restarting your phone.

Comment: Thanks. I tried restarting but no help.  I'll contact carrier tomorrow if it doesn't fix itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably call your carrier and ask them to sort it out.

From [this Apple Support article:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201618)

> Only your wireless carrier can access and manage the voicemail account for your phone number. On your carrier's customer-service page, look for steps about how to reset your password online or over the phone.